Clear Lua Output
I'm working on a project where you can be transported to an instructions page.
I am using a site called tutorialspoint and I am on Windows 10.
I need to be able the clear the terminal for a project, Is there a way to?
I tried a few commands like os.execute("clear") but it didn't work.

Lua, like its host C implementation, has no knowledge of terminal drivers. A solution here entirely depends on the platform and terminal in use (e.g., one might use ANSI escape sequences) - can you please provide this information? There are some fairly portable libraries (e.g., [tag:curses]) that tackle this problem, but do note that asking for library suggestions is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

On Linux terminal, try io.write("\27c")

On ANSI terminals, try io.write("\27[H\27[2J").

If you use Windows:
os.execute("cls")

On Unix:
os.execute("clear")

but I do recommend you read it: post
